# Para que serve a estrutura de dados virtual no DBeaver ou no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

Visualizando umas tabelas MySQL pelo DBeaver, notei uma aba chamada `Virtual`. Nela é possível criar **Colunas Virtuais**, **Chaves Estrangeiras Virtuais**, **Chaves Únicas Virtuais** e **Referências Virtuais**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual é a funcionalidade destes recursos? Como isso afeta o Banco de Dados? Qual a vantagem de utiliza-lo? Isso afeta o Banco de Dados MySQL ou é apenas mais um recurso do DBeaver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antes disso é preciso entender que para serem virtuais (ou não), elas precisam ser **colunas computadas**, ou seja, são valores calculados a partir de outras colunas. Isso é recurso presente não só no `MySQL`, existe também em outros bancos como o `SQL-Server` e `Oracle`, entre outros.

De uma forma muito simples, *virtual columns* não são persistidas, ou seja, seu conteúdo não é armazenado, apenas calculado.

Com mais detalhes, da documentação do `MySQL` aqui: [create-table-generated-columns.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

> The VIRTUAL or STORED keyword indicates how column values are stored,
> which has implications for column use:
>
> VIRTUAL: Column values are not stored, but are evaluated when rows are
> read, immediately after any BEFORE triggers. A virtual column takes no
> storage.
>
> InnoDB supports secondary indexes on virtual columns. See Section
> 13.1.18.8, “Secondary Indexes and Generated Columns”.
>
> STORED: Column values are evaluated and stored when rows are inserted
> or updated. A stored column does require storage space and can be
> indexed.
>
> The default is VIRTUAL if neither keyword is specified

Em tradução livre:

> A palavra-chave VIRTUAL ou STORED indica como os valores da coluna são
> armazenados, o que tem implicações para o uso da coluna:
>
> VIRTUAL: os valores da coluna não são armazenados, mas são avaliados
> quando as linhas são lidas, imediatamente após qualquer *trigger*
> BEFORE. Uma coluna virtual não requer armazenamento.
>
> InnoDB oferece suporte a índices secundários em colunas virtuais.
> Consulte a Seção 13.1.18.8, “Índices secundários e colunas geradas”.
>
> ARMAZENADO: os valores das colunas são avaliados e armazenados quando
> as linhas são inseridas ou atualizadas. Uma coluna armazenada requer
> espaço de armazenamento e pode ser indexada.
>
> O padrão é VIRTUAL se nenhuma palavra-chave for especificada

Ou seja, uma coluna com valor computado, pode ser persistida (STORED) no banco ou não (VIRTUAL).

Vamos pegar um exemplo simples:

```
CREATE TABLE Valores (
   valor DECIMAL(10,2),
   desconto  DECIMAL(10,2) AS (valor * 0.1) VIRTUAL,
   desconto2 DECIMAL(10,2) AS (valor * 0.2) STORED
);

INSERT INTO Valores(valor) VALUES (1000);

SELECT * FROM Valores;
```

As colunas `"desconto"` e `"desconto2"` são colunas computadas, ou seja, elas dependem da coluna `"valor"`, e calculam um desconto a partir de `"valor"`.

Entendido o conceito, vamos analisar a utilidade do VIRTUAL.

**Qual é a funcionalidade destes recursos?**

Permitir que uma coluna computada seja (STORED) ou não (VIRTUAL) armazenada junto com os demais dados da tabela.

**Como isso afeta o Banco de Dados?**

Primeiro devemos notar que, usar VIRTUAL/STORED ao criar uma coluna computada é opcional, e portanto **o padrão é VIRTUAL**. Isso parece meio óbvio, já que o valor é calculado a partir de outra coluna, isso poderia ser feito direto na query, portanto, a princípio não faz sentido ter esse valor armazenado, por isso o padrão é VIRTUAL. Então ele obviamente afeta o banco, uma vez que não ocupa espaço quando VIRTUAL.

**Qual a vantagem de utiliza-lo?**

A vantagem foi mencionada acima: ter um valor calculado que não precisa estar armazenado, uma vez que pode sempre ser calculado baseado em outra coluna.
Então, por quê usar o `STORED`? Imagina que por alguma razão precisasse indexar esse campo, isso não seria possível porque ele na realidade não existe na tabela, é VIRTUAL. Aqui entra a utilidade do STORED, ou seja, o campo computador armazenado pode ser utilizado em um índice, essa é a razão de ser do STORED.

**Isso afeta o Banco de Dados MySQL ou é apenas mais um recurso do DBeaver?**

Como comentado acima, isso é um recurso que existe em outros bancos de dados de forma semelhante, o `DBeaver` apenas fornece a interface para facilitar a sua criação/manutenção.

Note que, embora esteja presente em outros bancos de dados, é importante ver a documentação específica de cada um. Por exemplo, enquanto no `Oracle` também se usa VIRTUAL/STORED, no `SQL-Server` e no `MariaDB` é VIRTUAL/PERSISTED.

Comment: Chaves estrangeiras virtuais seguem essa mesma ideia?

Comment: não pode criar uma chave estrangeira para uma coluna computada, portanto não pode ser uma coluna virtual. Na própria documentação fala sobre isso aqui: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html  *"A foreign key constraint cannot reference a virtual generated column."*  Valores de chave precisam sem diretos e explicitamente definidos por isso uma coluna virtual não faz sentido ser usada como uma referencia de chave, estrangeira ou primária