# Rodar uma instrução no mysql de calculo de data de nascimento e atualizar a coluna idade

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma coluna chamada `data_nasc` e outra coluna idade, porém queria que toda vez que o sistema carregasse rodasse essa instrução dentro do MySQL e atualizasse o campo idade de todos os registros.

Até aqui funciona, porém o resultado sai na coluna temporária `ColunaCalculoIdade`, quero que o resultado atualizar os campo da coluna idade

```
SELECT        TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, data_nasc, CURRENT_DATE) AS ColunaCalculoIdade
FROM            clientes
```

Comment: por que não cria uma coluna computada que já vai calcular isso pra vc? eu comentei sobre isso nessa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/514534/para-que-serve-a-estrutura-de-dados-virtual-no-dbeaver-ou-no-mysql/516720#516720

Comment: lembre que só gravar na hora de incluir vai ter a idade naquele instante, no dia seguinte pode já estar desatualizado, uma coluna computada vai sempre calcular no instante da consulta :)

Comment: Normalmente não se grava idade no banco de dados. Só a data de nascimento já é suficiente para deduzir a idade.

Comment: Andei olhando a coluna computada, ainda muito complicada para um iniciante, o que quero é que quando abra o Form de cadastro o usuário faça uma consulta por idade e apareça os cadastros com a idade pesquisada ou quanto rodar o relatorio a idade ja vai atualizada, o máximo que consegui é fazer o codigo acima.

Comment: ja tentei usar assim:
**UPDATE clientes SET idade= SELECT  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, data_nasc, CURRENT_DATE) AS ColunaCalculoIdade FROM clientes**
Só queria que o resultado de calculo da data de nascimento atualizasse minha coluna idade.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi da seguinte fomra:

Coloquei um evento para rodar 24 HORAS POR DIA

**CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `CalculoIdade` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR STARTS '2021-07-17 00:00:01' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO UPDATE clientes SET idade = TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, data_nasc, CURRENT_DATE)**