# É possível criar uma coluna que receba o resultado de uma equação de outras colunas no postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Eu tenho uma tabela que possui duas colunas `VALOR` e `QDT`. Quero criar uma coluna `TOTAL` que recebe `VALOR * QDT`. É possível fazer somente com SQL?

Comment: sim é possível usando colunas computadas, pode ler mais sobre isso aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/514534/para-que-serve-a-estrutura-de-dados-virtual-no-dbeaver-ou-no-mysql/516720#516720  e na documentação: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html

Answer (score 2):

Conforme dito nos comentários, para criar a tabela com uma [coluna computada](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html):

```sql
CREATE TABLE tabela (
    valor numeric,
    qtd numeric,
    total numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS (valor * qtd) STORED
);
```

Se a tabela já existir, basta alterar uma  para isso:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tabela 
ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS total numeric
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (tabela.valor * tabela.qtd) STORED;
```

Vale notar que há diversas restrições que se aplicam à definição de colunas geradas e tabelas envolvendo colunas geradas. As principais, mas vale a pena consultar a documentação oficial, estão listadas abaixo:

- A expressão de geração só pode usar funções imutáveis e não pode usar subconsultas ou se referir a qualquer coisa além da linha atual de nenhuma maneira.
- A expressão de geração não pode se referir a outra coluna gerada.
- A expressão de geração não pode se referir a uma coluna de sistema, exceto [tableoid](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html).
- A coluna gerada não pode ter uma definição padrão de coluna ou uma definição de identidade.
- A coluna gerada não pode ser parte de uma chave de [particionamento](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html).

Comment: Olá Mansueli, tomei a liberdade de editar para que a resposta sirva para além do autor da pergunta (AP), assim servirá um pouco melhor para qualquer um que vier a buscar sobre como criar ou alterar. Eu estava a adicionar mais alguns detalhes, mas creio que isso você pode ter ideia melhor de como fazer, pois é importante citar que *colunas geradas* tem **diversas restrições**, e como a sua resposta pode atrair mais pessoas, por falta desses detalhes pode ser que seja melhor deixar claro isso na resposta, assim indo além do suporte pessoal. *Agradeço a compreensão*.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento `GENERATED ALWAYS AS (valor / total) STORED` não era pra ser `(valor * total)`? Só pra alinhar com a pergunta.

Comment: @CmteCardeal corrigido! 